# Bar graph and geom_line in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I am trying to draw a geom_line on a bar chart, my bars are filled by year.
My code is:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)
library(reshape)

DF <- data.frame(DECL.INDICATORS=c("Finland", "Finland", "Germany" ,"Germany","Italy","Italy"),
                 Year=c(2009,2010,2009,2010,2009,2010),
                 EXPVAL=c(2136410,1462620,371845300,402397520,357341970,357341970),
                 IMPVAL=c(-33668520,-37837140,-283300110,-306157870,-103628920,-105191850))


net <- ddply(DF, .(Year,DECL.INDICATORS), summarise, 
                net = sum(EXPVAL + IMPVAL))

DF.m <- melt(DF, id.vars = c("Year", "DECL.INDICATORS"))

ggplot(DF.m,aes(x=DECL.INDICATORS,y=value, fill=factor(Year)))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge",colour="darkgreen")

last_plot() + geom_line(data = net, aes(DECL.INDICATORS, net,group = 1), size = 1) + geom_hline(yintercept = 0,colour = "grey90")
```

Problem I am trying to resolve is to draw a three lines (net export from `net`) for each country Finland, Germany, Italy.

With my last code line  i am getting only three point which are connected with lines

Comment: Are you saying you want the lines to represent the net export over time for each country? Since the x-axis is currently country, that seem a bit non-intuitive.

Comment: @seaotternerd, Yes, but why non-intuitive, the origin data consists of 5 countries and 5 years. And i think it will represent dynamic of each country over time. I do not need to make comparison of countries, I would like to show a dynamic in each country

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use facets instead. That way it is clear that you are only comparing within one country and not between countries.

```
ggplot(DF.m, aes(x = factor(Year), y = value, fill = factor(Year))) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", colour="darkgreen") + 
  facet_grid(~DECL.INDICATORS) + 
  geom_line(data = net, aes(y = net, group = 1))
```