# Mapping Character Vs Double

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some fake sales data in which the Year variable is of character type and Sales variable is of double type.

I am trying to plot them in ggplot but can not do it. The geom_line() function only shows a straight line right in the middle of the graph and doesn't change according the the amount of sale.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30186936/bar-graph-and-geom-line-in-ggplot

Comment: also check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example before posting a question